# Can IntelliJ's Run/Debug configurations have prompts for input?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

i was wondering, if i can configure a run configuration (like executing a ruby script on a deployment server) with a prompt for parameters on starting the config. Like it does for starting rake tasks from the 'Run Rake Task...' after selecting a task.

I couldn't find anything in the run/debug config view and with a google search.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently found out that this feature is in fact implemented, kind of.
On the Run/Debug Configurations page there is a checkbox at the bottom called "Show this page". If you check this, everytime you want to start the config, you get a somewhat smaller version of the config page, letting you edit for example arguments and stuff.

Serves me quite well and yes, it is not fully what i need, but it does the job.

Answer (score 7):

It's not supported at the moment, related requests:

- [IDEA-152268](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152268) User prompted values in run configuration for "VM options" and "Program arguments"
- [IDEA-74031](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74031) Variables in command line parameters of run configuration